# Google Play Console - Android Bundle Permissions problem

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, bundler, google-play-console

I created my first android app in Expo, that i made the eject later on. I created the bundle and uploaded to the Google Play console, but in the list permissions appears:

```js
android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, 
android.permission.CAMERA, 
android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, 
android.permission.INTERNET, 
android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE, 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED, 
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, 
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, 
com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT, 
com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE, 
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE, 
com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE, 
com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION, 
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES, 
com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS, 
com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT, 
com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE, 
com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS, 
com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, 
com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE, 
com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS, 
com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, 
com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ, 
com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE, 
com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE, 
com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE, 
me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ, 
me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE
```

But in my **AndroidManifest.xml** i only have this:

```js
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I checked that the permissions that appear are merged with my **AndroidManifest.xml** in the build. These are permissions required by packages that I added to my project. To help check which packages are needed I go to **android > app > build > outputs > logs > manifest-merger-release-report.txt**.

Hope it help others with the same problem :)